# Question about Introspection / static_assert (C++17)

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a (container like) class that accepts several of my other types/classes as the data member. Now I would like to specify some properties (edit: positive integer) of the data type as compile time information. This works fine, but I would like to `static_assert` that the provided type is correct (uint8_t), the actual value is different for most data type classes. I set the number as a `std::integral_constant` with `uint8_t`.

1) How do I do that (see example code provided)?
2) Is there a better approach?

I can use language features up to c++17.

(**edited for clarification**)

```
class DataClass
{
     public:
        // compile time information about char count
        using char_count = std::integral_constant<uint8_t, 2>;

     private:
        ...
}

class DataClass2
{
     public:
        // compile time information about char count
        using char_count = std::integral_constant<uint8_t, 4>;

     private:
        ...
}

template <typename DataType, ...>
class ContainerClass
{
     private:
        // does not work: error C2923: 'std::is_same_v':
        // 'value' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '<unnamed-symbol>'
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<DataType::char_count::value, uint8_t>, "not uint8_t");
        // this also does not work
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(DataType::char_count::value), uint8_t>, "also not uint8_t");

        // using the value actually works fine
        constexpr static auto char_count = DataType::char_count::value;

     public:
        ...
}
```

Comment: Your 1st example has a typo: the argument list of `is_same_v` is terminated with `>` too early. For your 2nd, please define "also does not work". But ultimately, you're trying to compare a type with a value, so of course it won't work, in one way or another.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I only realized after. I expected decltype to do that but using the 2nd static_assert always fails even if char_count is `std::integral_constant<uint8_t, X>`. The correct solution seems to be using the `::value_type` of `std::integral_constant`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do depends on what exatly do you want to check.

1. Want to check that `char_count` has value 2? `static_assert(DataType::char_count::value == 2, "char_count is not 2!");`
2. Want to check that `char_count` is an integral constant (or something else) that has `uint8_t` as `type` member type alias ? `static_assert(std::is_same_v(typename DataType::char_count::value_type, "char_count is not uint8_t!");`
3. Want to checkt that `char_count` is an integral constant with value 2 and type `uint8_t`? `static_assert(std::is_same_v<DataType::char_count, std::integral_constant<uint8_t, 2>>, "char_count is not 2 or not uint8_t!");`

Comment: I don't want to check for the value but the type. `static_assert(std::is_same_v(typename DataType::char_count::type`, uint8_t>, "char_count is not uint8_t!");` seems to compile but does not work (is uint8_t implicitly converted to int or something else?!)

Comment: You need to elaborate on "does not work" whenever you say it, please.

Comment: I think the there was a typo in n314159s answer, it works with value_type instead of type

Comment: Yep, it is, had something wrong in mind. `std::integral_constant` has a type member but that is not interesting for your purpose, see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant)